# Composer setup of TYPO3 in exact version

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-10.x

Is it possible to require the whole TYPO3 and all of its components in exact version without putting this exact version to all components ? Pls. see part of my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
  "typo3/cms-core": "10.4.20",    
  "typo3/cms-about": "^10.4",
  "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^10.4",
  "typo3/cms-backend": "^10.4",
  "typo3/cms-belog": "^10.4",
  "typo3/cms-beuser": "^10.4",
```

In other words:
Do I have write "10.4.20" to all of the components below the the first line where I require the TYPO3 10.4.20 core or is there another way to do that with one line of code ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Just give it a try:

```
$ composer require typo3/cms-core:10.4.20 typo3/cms-about:^10.4
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update typo3/cms-core typo3/cms-about
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 63 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking cogpowered/finediff (0.3.1)
  ...
  - Locking typo3/class-alias-loader (v1.1.3)
  - Locking typo3/cms-about (v10.4.20)
  - Locking typo3/cms-cli (2.0.0)
  - Locking typo3/cms-composer-installers (v3.1.2)
  - Locking typo3/cms-core (v10.4.20)
  - Locking typo3/html-sanitizer (v2.0.13)
  ...
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 63 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing typo3/cms-composer-installers (v3.1.2): Extracting archive
  ...
  - Installing cogpowered/finediff (0.3.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing typo3/cms-core (v10.4.20): Extracting archive
  - Installing typo3/cms-about (v10.4.20): Extracting archive
6 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Generating autoload files
Generating class alias map file
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the same version number for all `typo3/cms-*` packages. With search & replace that should be quite easy.